# Removing duplicate elements in place from a list of sorted integers

Tags: python

I want to remove duplicate elements from a list and return the list that has only unique values. Here is my code

```
def remove_dup(nums):
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        if nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
            nums.remove(nums[i])
    return nums
```

I am testing the code with this :

```
print(remove_dup([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]))
```

I was expecting the output to be [1,2,3,4] but I am getting [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]. Can anyone please explain, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: You’re modifying the list while iterating over it (the indexes anyway) which is nearly always a bad idea. To remove duplicates you can just turn the list into a set and then back into a list

Comment: convert your list to `set` and then to list, simple. list(set([0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]))

Answer (score 1):

Because you shouldn't increase `i` in those iterations when an element is removed. This makes you jump two elements ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your list to a set like so:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
print(list(set(my_list)))
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```